# Spring-boot dependency problems

Tags: spring-boot

I'm trying to upgrade our project from Spring-boot 1.4.3 to 2.0.4.RELEASE;

Here is my current pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>SpreadSheetUploadWeb</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpreadSheetUploadWeb</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring.version>4.3.9.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.boot.version>2.0.4.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
        <db2.driver.version>10.5.9</db2.driver.version>
        <spring.batch.version>3.0.8.RELEASE</spring.batch.version>
        <tomcat.version>8.5.6</tomcat.version>
        <poi.version>3.15</poi.version>
        <sonar.coverage.exclusions>**/BlueCostSpreadsheetUploadWebApplication.java</sonar.coverage.exclusions>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- POI dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>${poi.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>${poi.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>${poi.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- DB2 dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.db2.jcc</groupId>
            <artifactId>db2jcc_license_cisuz</artifactId>
            <version>${db2.driver.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.db2.jcc</groupId>
            <artifactId>db2jcc4</artifactId>
            <version>${db2.driver.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- HSQLDB dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JJD adding to make REST Test cases work 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180130</version>
        </dependency -->

        <!-- JJD adding Sonarqube dependency  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0.905</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        <!-- JJD The next two are for generating Swagger Documents for REST api documentation -->
        <dependency>     
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>     
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>     
            <version>2.9.2</version>    
        </dependency>    
        <dependency>     
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>     
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>     
            <version>2.9.2</version>    
        </dependency>           
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>bluecost-spreadsheet-web</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            </plugin>           
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>AT*</exclude>
                        <exclude>IT*</exclude>
                        <exclude>BlueCostSpreadsheetUploadTestSuite</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                    <skipTests>${skip.surefire.tests}</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                     <execution>
                        <id>integration-tests</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>TestApplicationProperties</exclude>
                                <exclude>UTSampleTests</exclude>
                                <exclude>FT*</exclude>
                                <exclude>UT*</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                            <!-- Sets the VM argument line used when integration tests are run. -->
                            <argLine>${failsafeArgLine}</argLine>
                            <!--
                                Skips integration tests if the value of skip.integration.tests property
                                is true
                            -->
                            <skipTests>${skip.failsafe.tests}</skipTests>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!--
                Unit Test Jacoco Reports
            -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <!--
                        Prepares the property pointing to the JaCoCo runtime agent which
                        is passed as VM argument when Maven the Surefire plugin is executed.
                    -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>pre-unit-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <skipTests>${skip.surefire.tests}</skipTests>
                            <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
                            <destFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</destFile>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <!--
                        Ensures that the code coverage report for unit tests is created after
                        unit tests have been run.
                    -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>post-unit-test</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <skipTests>${skip.surefire.tests}</skipTests>
                            <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
                            <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</dataFile>
                            <!-- Sets the output directory for the code coverage report. -->
                            <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-ut</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>           
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Now, when I run 'mvn test' on existing test cases, I get the following error:

```
[INFO] Running com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.spreadsheet.controller.UTBlueCostRestControllerTests
Aug 06, 2018 5:19:12 PM org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTestContextBootstrapper buildDefaultMergedContextConfiguration
INFO: Neither @ContextConfiguration nor @ContextHierarchy found for test class [com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.spreadsheet.controller.UTBlueCostRestControllerTests], using SpringBootContextLoader
Aug 06, 2018 5:19:12 PM org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader generateDefaultLocations
INFO: Could not detect default resource locations for test class [com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.spreadsheet.controller.UTBlueCostRestControllerTests]: no resource found for suffixes {-context.xml, Context.groovy}.
Aug 06, 2018 5:19:12 PM org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoaderUtils detectDefaultConfigurationClasses
INFO: Could not detect default configuration classes for test class [com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.spreadsheet.controller.UTBlueCostRestControllerTests]: UTBlueCostRestControllerTests does not declare any static, non-private, non-final, nested classes annotated with @Configuration.
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.083 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.spreadsheet.controller.UTBlueCostRestControllerTests
[ERROR] initializationError(com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.spreadsheet.controller.UTBlueCostRestControllerTests)  Time elapsed: 0.015 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.Assert.state(ZLjava/util/function/Supplier;)V
```

I found some threads on this topic that indicate that there is a problem with the classpath - most likely that spring-core is in the classpath twice, but I can't locate the problem.   I've printed the dependendency tree using mvn dependency plugin as an aid in troubleshooting, but I don't see anything obviously wrong.  Please help:

```
[INFO] Verbose not supported since maven-dependency-plugin 3.0
[WARNING] The artifact org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:pom:3.4.0.905 has been relocated to org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:pom:3.4.0.905
[INFO] SpreadSheetUploadWeb:SpreadSheetUploadWeb:jar:1.0
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.19:runtime
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:2.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.zaxxer:HikariCP:jar:2.7.9:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.5.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.5.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.5.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.11.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:2.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.0.4.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.0.4.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.0.4.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.4.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3:test
[INFO] |  |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.2:test
[INFO] |  |        \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.4:test
[INFO] |  +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.9.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:2.15.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.7.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.7.11:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.6:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.5.1:test
[INFO] +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:jar:3.15:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.github.virtuald:curvesapi:jar:1.04:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.15:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.11:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:jar:4.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:jar:3.15:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.ibm.db2.jcc:db2jcc_license_cisuz:jar:10.5.9:compile
[INFO] +- com.ibm.db2.jcc:db2jcc4:jar:10.5.9:compile
[INFO] +- org.hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:2.4.0:test
[INFO] +- org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:pom:3.4.0.905:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-sec-dispatcher:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-cipher:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.22:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.sonarsource.scanner.api:sonar-scanner-api:jar:2.10.0.1189:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.flywaydb:flyway-core:jar:5.0.7:compile
[INFO] +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.swagger:swagger-annotations:jar:1.5.20:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.swagger:swagger-models:jar:1.5.20:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-spi:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.springfox:springfox-core:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-schema:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-common:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-spring-web:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:20.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-core:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-metadata:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.mapstruct:mapstruct:jar:1.2.0.Final:compile
[INFO] \- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:jar:2.9.2:compile
```

I should Add that I have run the following commands on my machine after the version update:

mvn clean 
mvn eclipse:clean
mvn eclipse:eclipse

Project update in Eclipse.  I can maybe try to re-import to another workspace, but at this point I'm out of ideas and need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Release-Notes#third-party-library-upgrades and https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide#dependency-versions, you need to upgrade your Spring version to 5.x.

In your pom.xml, change

`<spring.version>4.3.9.RELEASE</spring.version>`

to

`<spring.version>5.0.8.RELEASE</spring.version>`

You might need to do some more changes for this migration of major spring version.

Comment: Thanks very much!  It worked, like a magic charm from the land of Oz!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the parent as Spring Boot, have a dependency Management with Spring boot Bill of Materials.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

This way  you don't have to a manually add the version numbers for each dependency.

Ex:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
        </dependency>

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

You can view the dependency and version details from here.
http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/2.0.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-dependencies-2.0.2.RELEASE.pom

Comment: If you take a look at the - [link](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/2.0.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-dependencies-2.0.2.RELEASE.pom) in the properties tag you can see all the the versions specified. This way you don't have to give the versions, it will take check the property tag and apply the version. In can you want to override the existing dependency you can override it with your version. This way you never have to worry about version mismatch anymore.